# docker running but can't access on the server

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have stages for Jenkins jobs to test and deploy my nodejs with docker, I run docker on port 3000 but when I tried to browser my `ip-server:3000`, it doesn't work and nothing 
my dockers are running

here is my Jenkinsfile

```
node {
  try {
    stage('Checkout') {
      checkout scm
    }
    stage('Environment') {
      sh 'git --version'
      echo "Branch: ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
      sh 'docker -v'
      sh 'printenv'
    }
    stage('Build Docker test'){
     sh 'docker build -t crud-test -f Dockerfile.test --no-cache .'
    }
    stage('Docker test'){
      sh 'docker run --rm crud-test'
    }
    stage('Clean Docker test'){
      sh 'docker rmi crud-test'
    }
    stage('Deploy'){
      if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master'){
        sh 'docker build -t crud --no-cache .'
        sh 'docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -e DB_USERNAME=myusername -e DB_PASSWORD=12345678 -e DB_NAME=employee crud'
      }
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Extending image
FROM node:carbon

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get -y install autoconf automake libtool nasm make pkg-config git apt-utils

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Versions
RUN npm -v
RUN node -v

COPY ./server/ /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

# Port to listener
EXPOSE 3000

# Environment variables
ENV PORT 4000
ENV DB_USERNAME myusername
ENV DB_PASSWORD 12345678
ENV DB_NAME employee

# Main command
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

I run Jenkins via docker-compose on my ubuntu server,
is that something I missing or wrong ?? 
because my goal here using Jenkins to test my server and after the test successfully it gonna deploy my Nodejs on my ubuntu server 
so after building finish on Jenkins, I could browser my server API on the browser to make sure it works on `ip-sever:3000`

but on the above pipeline, is that correct that job do every time I push to master, my server API will be updated without click `build now` on Jenkins? if not, how to configure it?

I am also don't know how to hide my ENV, so I show up on my stage Jenkinsfile because on multibranches pipeline does not have any option for env parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see your env variable port 4000 is that your server port ? If it's so you have to change docker run command to map port 4000 to work on port 3000 in your host, or you can change your env variable Port to be 3000

Comment: Please also check container logs by command docker logs command and double check that your server is working and no errors .

Comment: Please try first to connect to your app through localhost: port, if you are trying to connect through ip or from other pc  you have pass host `0.0.0.0` in `server.listen`  `app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log('Listening to port:  ' + 3000);
});`

Comment: it is still same, nothing change

Comment: Did you checked docker logs ? , Please write the current code for Jenkins, docker file , server.js

Comment: all here , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683975/docker-running-but-cant-access-on-the-server/57685049?noredirect=1#comment101837116_57685049 , i asked again LOL

Comment: I think it's the same url for this question, please write the other question link  :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57692740/docker-run-on-container-but-not-run-on-server here

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that most probably Jenkins is spawning a container to run your build.

If that container for build does not use docker engine from host but uses "docker-in-docker" your `docker run` command does expose port 3000 not on your host but on container on that host running dind.

Try runnning `docker ps` and see what containers are running on your host and see if the tested container is there. If it is there, examine by `docker inspect` what exacly it does, what ports does it expose, etc.

You can also inspect docker 'nat' network to see if port 3000 is really forwarded to host.

Comment: my docker ps for that docker image something like this :  `0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp`

Comment: What `ENV PORT` does? What is it for?

Comment: that is for my port, but  till now my server not working with its docker