# docker run on container but not run on server

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, jenkins, docker-compose

i create Jenkinsfile, Dockerfile, Dockerfile.test to CI and CD my server API on GitHub, i build it on Jenkins and the build was successfully, and my docker run on the container as well,
on Jenkinsfile stages, i create for test and deploy on server API,
and using docker for the container

i also run Jenkins on docker also,
using docker-compose

here is my Dockerfile on my ubuntu server

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root
```

and here is my docker-compose on ubuntu server

```
version: '3'

services:

  jenkins:
    build: .
    container_name: jenkins
    privileged: true
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker

  registry:
    image: registry
    container_name: registry
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

what i did above , i follow [this intruction](https://hackernoon.com/continuous-delivery-of-react-app-with-jenkins-and-docker-8a1ae1511b86)
then i tried ro run it and login on my jenkins server,

my jenkinsfile something like this

```
  try {
    stage('Checkout') {
      checkout scm
    }
    stage('Environment') {
      sh 'git --version'
      echo "Branch: ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
      sh 'docker -v'
      sh 'printenv'
    }
    stage('Build Docker test'){
     sh 'docker build -t employee-test -f Dockerfile.test --no-cache .'
    }
    stage('Docker test'){
      sh 'docker run --rm employee-test'
    }
    stage('Clean Docker test'){
      sh 'docker rmi employee-test'
    }
    stage('Deploy'){
      if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master'){
        sh 'docker build -t employee --no-cache .'
        sh 'docker run -d -p 4000:4000 -e DB_USERNAME=admin -e DB_PASSWORD=adminxxx -e DB_NAME=employee employee'
      }
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
}
```

and my Dockerfile for those jobs

```
FROM node:carbon

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get -y install autoconf automake libtool nasm make pkg-config git apt-utils

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm -v
RUN node -v

COPY ./server/ /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4000

ENV PORT 4000
ENV DB_USERNAME admin
ENV DB_PASSWORD adminxxx
ENV DB_NAME employee

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

the jenkins job build it successfully and on the last stage my Jenkins, u can see that i run it on my docker container on my ubuntu server, after that finish, i tried to call server API on postman for `http://ip-server:4000` , but it was nothing response, and i did set up the firewall tcp on my ubuntu serrver though

how can i solve this? so after Jenkins job finish, what i want i could call that server API on my postman to test it

Comment: did you check on the server if the docker container is up and running?

Comment: the status up `26 mins`, so it is running i bet @Stefano

Comment: while on the server, did you try to run a curl against it?

Comment: just did but nothing, when i `docker port numCintaineHere` it said my port on 4000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:4000 , so i call my api with ip-server:4000 , and nothing

Comment: are you sure that the container is up to date? I don't see any command to shut it down. it might be that you're trying to test something older.

Comment: do i miss something? @Stefano , this is my first time using jenkins and docker, so i dont know much what to do, that is why i ask :)

Comment: your status as DevOps on StackOverflow, so i am sure u know why if you are real DevOps :) @Stefano

Comment: can you please add the log of a Jenkins build?

Comment: https://slexy.org/view/s2adQ6B8Ez here @Stefano

Comment: the local port changed and I think the reason is that it fails when trying to bind the port 4000 more than once. Does it work when you connect on the `server_ip:3000`?

Comment: nope it doesn work, so how to solve this ?do i missing something ?

Comment: i have tried all port for dockerfile and jenkins stage, but not work on my server

Comment: ok, so beside the problem with removing the old containers I don't see anything else wrong. I've checked the instructions link you added and I noticed that the the Dockerfile is starting the application using the dev environment (which uses webpack). If you didn't change the webpack configuration it might be that the port mapping is not correct.

Comment: i dont know what is that, can you answer on my question what i should change to fix that problem ?

Comment: mmmh, is this a react app? if you didn't change the port, you should map the port 3000 not 4000. BTW are you sure that the application works locally? It'd make little sense to test something that doesn't work locally...

Comment: this is only my express js API , not react, just back end , what is i should change ? on dockerfile or jenkifile ? yes i run on locally machine on my ubuntu server, my docker on my ubuntu server and jenkins also

Comment: if the git repo is public, it'd be easier to check there

Comment: IMPORTANT: remove the DB password from the repository if it's a valid one and change the DB password.

Comment: it was work, because when i do test i am using that ENV password and it was work on my mongodb, anything wrong again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration looks good, So it seems that docker compose caching the volumes so please run this commands to cleanup every thing

```
 docker rm employee
 docker image rm employee
 docker-compose down -v 
 docker-compose up
```

Please make sure that jenkins log this

```
'docker run -d -p 4000:4000 -e DB_USERNAME=admin -e DB_PASSWORD=adminxxx -e DB_NAME=employee employee'
```

Comment: should i add that command on Jenkins file ?? because my docker-compose not integration on GitHub, it run locally on machine ubuntu server

Comment: Run docker-compose commands in the machine which have the running Jenkins dockers inside Jenkins folder , which have docker-compose file , and other commands ( rm ) to be run in the machine which have node docker container

Comment: Docker rm xx wil remove node app container, docker image rm will remove node app image, Docker-compose down will stop Jenkins server, compose up will run Jenkins server again, so please run all commands in the same order.

Comment: do you mean during build ?

Comment: that is about port i think, oh yea, is my jenkinsfile configuration will do job e=change eveyrtime i oush to master \?

Comment: Yes you can add docker rm commands in build stages , before docker build command, also please add `docker stop employee` before all, that's will stop container other two will remove container and image , to clean up every thing, regarding to docker-compose commands you need to run it manually in case of changing Jenkins file or updating Jenkins container.